# How to fix JS interaction makes button not responsible and Why

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView and one singleton view with some buttons.(I also have a xib file for this singleton view and the singleton is created with this xib file)

When the webview loaded the request, buttons on the view work fine. But after I did any javascript interaction in my webview, all buttons in the singleton view didn't response any actions (I bind the button actions from xib to the singleton view) any more. I have no clue at all why it happens and how to fix it.

I tried to connect the button IBOutlet with the singleton view but the app would crash.
I checked the subviews of the singleton every button is still here.

I expect the buttons would work no matter what javascript interaction happens but the actual is any javascript interaction would make button not responding.

Comment: Apart from the buttons not responding, does your JavaScript continue working? Most chances are your code throws an error and the execution of JavaScript stops completely.

Comment: Yes my JavaScript works fine. And I think the js error won’t effect my native button’s functionality. I am still so confused